# Factory Method without memory allocation C++

Tags: c++, design-patterns, factory, factory-method

I have been searching for factory method without memory allocation and I have not found anything yet.

I want to make an inheritance tree like this:

```
Controller_Base_Class
   |                |
Specific_Class1     Specific_Class2 ...
```

In all factory methods that I've seen the helper class that creates the actual specific class, allocates memory with **new** and returns the object. For some reasons I would like to do it without new memory allocation.

Having that there won't be much Specific classes, would it make sense that the helper class had a reference of every Specific class and returns the one I need?
Something like:

```
class BaseClass
{
   whatever
}

class Specific1 : public BaseClass
{
   whatever
}

class Specific2 : public BaseClass
{
   whatever
}

class Factory
{
    public:
        Factory();
        BaseClass* Create(SpecType type);
    private:
        Specific1 specific1;
        Specific2 specific2;
}
Factory::Factory() : specific1(), specific2()
{
}
BaseClass* Factory::Create(SpecType type)
{
    if(type==SpecType1)
    {
        return &specific1;
    }
    ...
}

...
//function where i want to do it
Factory factory = Factory()
BaseClass* inheritance_holder = factory.Create(Spec1Type);
...
```

Comment: The outline you have should work,as long as the classes are actually derived from base, does it not?

Comment: I assume that `Specific1` and `Specific2` both inherits from `BaseClass`? If that's so, then what's the problem with your shown code?

Comment: Ups, yes, they both inherit from BaseClass, i forgot to put it sorry

Comment: It's not a problem, i was asking whether the approach was correct.

Comment: It is not longer a *"factory"* as calling twice `factory.Create(Spec1Type)` would return twice the same pointer.

Comment: @Jarod42 you just beat me by half a minute

Comment: More of a "get instance" than a "create".

Comment: This is more like a multi-instance singleton than a factory.

Comment: _"For some reasons I would like to do it without new memory allocation..."_: are you sure these are good reasons? Maybe you should tell us about that. Maybe this is an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/), not sure unless you tell us more.

Comment: The client forbids it for security reasons. I want to Have that kind of hierarchy and have only one instance of any of them depending on a configuration file.

Comment: @GontzalAparicio That sounds like you want a singleton whose concrete type is determined at runtime. If that's what you want, you can use placement new with a statically allocated memory buffer.

Comment: @GontzalAparicio you definitely need to elaborate your question, it's quite unclear what you're trying to achieve and you obviously misuse the terms _factory_ and _factory method_.

Comment: @Jabberwocky That's why I'm asking. Having that hierarchy in mind, I can only have one specific class active at runtime and it has to be the same during all the lifetime. I read from a conf file which Specific class shall be active and all the operations to be done shall be specific to that class. I don't know if I have clarified it.

Comment: @GontzalAparicio -- It looks like you simply took the everyday `switch` statement that determines which derived object to use at runtime, and just placed that code in a class.  For example, `type_to_use* t; switch(type) { case 1: t = &type_1; break; case 2; t = &type_2; break; case 3: t = &type_3; break; `, etc.

Comment: @GontzalAparicio: For that sort of client, I advice to use `std::make_shared<T>`. Technically still a memory allocation, but safer and definitely no `new` (in your code).